# How do I make dark oak material in BLENDER

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I want to make a 3D model of a speaker (Fyne Audio F501) but not able to make the dark oak wood material for Cycles can anyone help?[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Just to clarify - are you asking about *procedural textures*, or how to darken/recolor an *image texture*?

Comment: Whichever method works or look similar to the reference.

Comment: Okay. When you said you're not able to get the right material, what have you got so far? Just add another image into your post :).

Comment: Will find your question better received if you show the result(s) you have so far.

Comment: Actually I am Learning Blender. Just added an image texture node, roughness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily recolor any image texture using nodes.

[image]

1. Start with a suitable wood texture. Choose by pattern, you'll adjust the color.
   There are many free ones on the Interwebs (god, i love that word).
   I used [this free one from Poliigon](https://www.poliigon.com/texture/wood-fine-dark-004)
2. Connect it into the *Base color* input
3. Adjust colors using RGB curves/Hue saturation node... whatever you like.
   Blender offers many [Color nodes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/color/index.html) just for this.
   Just connect the node in front of your image texture like in my image.

[image]

*Source image texture*
[image]

**Note:**
If you're a beginner I reccomend [BlenderGuru's Donut tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjEaoINr3zgEq0u2MzVgAaHEBt--xLB6U).
You'll learn everything you need there :).